# Código en Python para ordenar las sentencias de un texto según su longitud en cuanto a número de palabras

Tags: python, procesamiento-de-texto

Soy nueva en este área y en la uni nos han dado un ejercicio de Python en el cual tenemos que ordenar las frases de un texto según su longitud: de la que más palabras tiene a la que menos. Alguna idea? Me estoy volviendo loca!
He conseguido el código para saber el número de palabras por oración:

```
text="We have developed speed, but we have shut ourselves in. Machinery that gives abundance has left us in want. Our knowledge has made us cynical. Our cleverness, hard and unkind. We think too much and feel too little. More than machinery  we  need  humanity.  More  than  cleverness  we  need  kindness  and gentleness."

listaOraciones = text.split('. ')


for oracion in listaOraciones:
    print(oracion, str(len(oracion.split(' '))))
```

Ahora necesitaría ordenarlas en de la más larga a la más corta

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque pide que le hagan la tarea

Comment: Antes de votar por cerrar la pregunta. elisa, ¿podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir el código con lo que has intentado hasta ahora para resolverlo? De esta forma la comunidad podrá echarte una mano. En cuanto a resolver fallos, mejorar un poco tu código o ayudarte a finalizarlo por dudas que de ninguna forma puedas resolver puede ayudarte la comunidad. Para realizar todo un ejercicio desde 0, no. Sino se considera, como bien indica @Candid, un "hazme la tarea. Te invito a leer el enlace de "cómo preguntar" [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi solución, por pasos:

```
text="We have developed speed, but we have shut ourselves in. Machinery that gives abundance has left us in want. Our knowledge has made us cynical. Our cleverness, hard and unkind. We think too much and feel too little. More than machinery  we  need  humanity.  More  than  cleverness  we  need  kindness  and gentleness."
```

`text.split(".")` divide el texto en oraciones:

```
['We have developed speed, but we have shut ourselves in', 
 ' Machinery that gives abundance has left us in want', 
 ' Our knowledge has made us cynical', 
 ' Our cleverness, hard and unkind', 
 ' We think too much and feel too little', 
 ' More than machinery  we  need  humanity', 
 '  More  than  cleverness  we  need  kindness  and gentleness', 
 '']
```

Luego queremos dividir cada oración en palabras.

Usaremos `split()`, que sin argumentos separada por espacios en blanco y formaremos una lista de tuplas donde el primer elemento es el número de palabras en la oración y el segundo, el texto de la oración:

```
[(len(sent.split()), sent) for sent in text.split(".")]
```

A continuación la ordenamos con `sorted`, usando la opción de ordenar descendente:

```
sorted([(len(sent.split()), sent) for sent in text.split(".")], reverse=True)
```

Luego, imprimimos la lista de tuplas:

```
for linea in sorted([(len(sent.split()), sent) for sent in text.split(".")], reverse=True):
    print(linea)
```

produce:

```
(10, 'We have developed speed, but we have shut ourselves in')
(9, ' Machinery that gives abundance has left us in want')
(8, ' We think too much and feel too little')
(8, '  More  than  cleverness  we  need  kindness  and gentleness')
(6, ' Our knowledge has made us cynical')
(6, ' More than machinery  we  need  humanity')
(5, ' Our cleverness, hard and unkind')
(0, '')
```

Comment: Buena solución (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo conseguí! Lo dejo aquí por si a alguien pudiera servirle. Gracias!

```
text="We have developed speed, but we have shut ourselves in. Machinery that gives abundance has left us in want. Our knowledge has made us cynical. Our cleverness, hard and unkind. We think too much and feel too little. More than machinery  we  need  humanity.  More  than  cleverness  we  need  kindness  and gentleness."

for i in reversed(sorted(text.split("."), key=lambda sentence: len(sentence))):
    print (i)
```